# Anonymous functions and parameters

Tags: javascript, performance

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 'no'
    setInterval(function() { console.log(bar); }, 1000);
}
```

When I execute this piece of code, I got the following output: `no`, so the output is correct. But when I execute the next piece of code, when I pass the function `bar`as a parameter to that anonymous function, I don't know exactly why the output is `undefined`

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 'no'
    setInterval(function(bar) { console.log(bar); }, 1000);
}
```

If I pass the variable as a parameter, why is undefined? If there was also a variable call `bar` inside the anonymous function, I know that variable would be rewritten with the inner function value, but I can't understand this behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example you create a closure -- the function you create is linked to the `bar` variable. It is not passed to the function as a parameter. When `setInterval` later calls the function without providing any parameters, it works as expected because the function has closed over `bar` variable.

In your second example you don't pass the variable as a parameter. You describe a function that accepts one parameter, and is not closed over anything. Then later `setInterval` calls that function in the same way, providing no parameters. If a parameter is not provided in javascript, it becomes `undefined`.

(You can call a function in js with any number of parameters, regardless what parameters the function is declared with).

More reading about closures: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/11683)

Answer (score 1):

When the callback is called, it is called without parameters by [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), so the argument `bar`, which shadows the external `bar`, is `undefined`.

You can pass the parameter as argument of `setInterval` :

```
setInterval(function(bar) { console.log(bar); }, 1000, bar);
```